# Python: how to manage a variable's lifetime beyond a single function?

Tags: python, resources, lifetime, with-statement, raii

I'm looking to better understand how Python can be used to guarantee resource release when the lifetime of the resource extends beyond a single function.

The go-to answer for the general problem of ensuring a resource is released, is to use a `with` statement, and sometimes to create a context manager to wrap the resource and manage its lifetime. However *in every single example of this*, the resource is used immediately and then is no longer required. It all takes place in a single function, and there's never any demonstration of saving, returning, or storing the resource.

The `with` approach does not seem to handle some important cases, such as when resource creation occurs in a different place from the resource usage. Compared with the RAII concept from C++, it seems deficient.

Aside: I've come to understand that the `__del__` function is not suitable as a place to release resources, as there's no guarantee that it will even run, and if it does, it may not be until the very end of the program, and this may never happen.

For example, consider a class that creates or opens a resource (such as a file handle) in the initialiser function, *which is then saved to be used later*, at a time controlled by the owner of the `Foo` instance:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._f = open("/tmp/foo", "w")

    def close(self):
        if self._f:
            self._f.close()

    def do_something(self):
        some_func(self._f)
```

This could be turned into a context manager with:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._f = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self._f = open("/tmp/foo", "w")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.close()

    def close(self):
        if self._f:
            f.close()

    def do_something(self):
        some_func(self._f)
```

Then callers can ensure the file is closed, e.g. in the event of exceptions, if they remember to do:

```
with Foo() as foo:
    foo.do_something()
```

But what if the instance of Foo, and its open file object, is to have a long lifetime? For example:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = Foo()

    def later(self):
        self._foo.do_something()

bar = Bar()
# time passes...
bar.later()
# program eventually ends but nobody cleaned up bar._foo!
```

What do we do here? We can't use a `with` in `__init__` because this simply doesn't work - the context manager releases Foo's resource when the `with` block completes:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        with Foo() as foo:
            self._foo = foo

        # foo.__exit__() has been called! Thus self._foo is not useful.
```

So we also have to make `Bar` a context manager that manages the `Foo` resource:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self._foo = Foo()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self._foo:
            self._foo.close()

    def later(self):
        self._foo.do_something()
```

This seems to propagate the context manager pattern up through the structure, and it gets a lot worse when you start composing multiple classes that handle their own resources.

```
# perhaps not so bad with two classes:
with Foo() as foo, Bar(foo) as bar: 
    bar.later()

# terrible with more (these all need to be context managers!):
with Foo() as foo, Bar(foo) as bar, Baz(bar) as baz, Goo(foo, baz) as goo: 
    goo.some_function()
```

Since "whoever opens the file must close the file", this also seems to suggest that all file objects could be created at the top level and injected instead, but not all resources are file objects and it makes more sense to have classes that encapsulate them.

Other than having a top-level multi-part `with` statement and dependency-injecting every single instance of anything that manages a resource, what is a good way to deal with the requirement that all of these resources are eventually cleaned up, ideally without requiring the programmer to remember to write complex `try/except/finally` blocks that call `close` or equivalent?

Comment: In my view, context managers are not helpful for long-term situations.  (Personally, I think they are overused.)  When the Foo object goes out of scope, the file will be closed.  If the two are intended to have a paired lifetime, that's a perfectly reasonable strategy,